# How to insert Null Values of type double in ANDROID

Tags: android

I created a table with six cloumns as described below when am i putting the null vales in second row of type double it shows error.

How to put empty values in double place

```
myDB.insert("Hotel MidCity",16.5048,80.6338,"Vijayawada",16.251,80.666);
myDB.insert("Minerva Hyderabad",16.5024,80.6432,"Null", , );
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitive variable `double` cannot be null, and cannot be compared with a Java null. If you want to assign null value or no value for this double variable then you have to give value like 0.0.